# Height issue with news posts (length of title messes up formatting)

Tags: css

I'm having this issue with news posts. The image makes it pretty self-explanatory. How do I use CSS to fix this? Image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/25a47fd31b1141e0af17c4960c3be011.png

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure, what is wrong or right with the css on the linked image. But with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), such `divs` can be positioned in a more advanced way.